# file name contains spaces can't open with fopen

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm writing a program which counts how many times each C keyword is contained in an ASCII file selected by the user. So I use scanf to save the name that the user selected as filename and check with fopen if a file with that name exists in the same dir as the C program. The problem lies in the fact that if the filename selected by the user contains spaces fopen gives an error because it can't find such a file. So here's the question, how do I open a file with fopen that contains spaces in the name of it? Here is the code that i used for the program

```
selectfilename(filein,1) ;
if (fopen(filein,"r") == NULL){
    perror("Error ") ;
    return (1) ;
}

void selectfilename(char *cp, int num){
    if (num == 1) printf("Please select the name of the file to be opened  including the extension : ") ;               
    else printf("Please select the name of the file to save the statistics including the extension : ") ;               
    scanf("%s",cp++) ;
}
```

Comment: "Here is the code that i used for the program" - This will not even compile! Read [ask].

Comment: There has to be more code than that.

Comment: here is the code that has to do with the question!! there is no need to post all the 60 lines of it because they are irrelevant to the problem. It goes without saying that this can't be all the code.

Comment: You should `printf("[%s]\n", filein)`

Comment: @user3386109 it did'nt help. Let's say I want to open a file that has the name "A D R.txt". Even though the char array that I created storing the name is exactly "A D R.txt" when i try to pass the array as an argument to the fopen function it doesn't work. I understand that it has to do with the spaces and the fact that fopen treats space,\t ,\r as EOL and doesn't go all the way to the real EOL when the enter is pressed

Comment: print what scanf have read in and you'll know why

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is with `scanf`, not `fopen` – which handles filenames with spaces just fine.

`scanf("%s")` only parse until the first space. It's hard to propose a fix without seeing more of the code.

**Update:**
Since you read from stdin you can try this to read until the line terminator.

```
char buf[256];
int rv = scanf ("%255[^\n]", buf);  // 255 is max chars to read
if (rv == 0 || rv == EOF)
    buf[0] = 0;
printf ("[%s]\n", buf);
```

**Update 2**: Fixed bugs reported by @chux

Comment: the rest of the code is really just for counting how many times the keywords exist in the file. I don't have a problem with that part. The problem is that if
the file name contains spaces it can't be opened using fopen

Comment: Yea, ok. I think I figured it out based on the code you posted.

Comment: you are right it doesn't work with scanf. Is there any better function to use?

Comment: See the updated answer. It works with `scanf`, but you must use a format specifier that don't stop parsing at a space. `fgets` might be a better option.

Comment: it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that if the first character entered is a `'\n'`, then `scanf ("%255[^\n]", buf);  printf ("[%s]\n", buf);` leads to UB as nothing is changed in the uninitialized `buf[]`.  Other issues too.  Better to use `fgets()` and lop off the potential trailing `'\n'`

Comment: @chux I have not checked the standard, but on my system `scanf` will always insert a null terminator. I'm pretty sure that is standard behaviour. (That's also why `buf` is one byte larger than the size specifier to `scanf`).

Comment: @TorkelBjørnson-Langen "scanf will always insert a null terminator."  --> No - that is not always true.  If the first character is a `'\n'`, nothing is read, `'\n'` remains in `stdin`, `buf[]` is unchanged, no null character appended.  The number 256/256 is not applicable in that case.

Comment: @chux Ok, sorry. My bad. `scanf` will only insert the null terminator when something is actually read. Thank you for noticing. I will update the answer to fix that bug.

Comment: Should you care: on a _rare_ input error, the state of `buf[]` is indeterminate.  Prior `buf[0] = 0;` does not help.  Like all input functions, good code checks the return value of `scanf()` and handles things accordingly.